# How to put the next day date below existing date value using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My `df` looks like this. It is a `daily` `dataset` except the `Saturday`:

```
time    
2019-01-04       
2019-01-01  
2019-01-07 
2019-01-03 
....
```

What I want to do is to find the next day `date` and put it below each `time` value except `Saturday`. If the next data is `Saturday`then skip it.

We should preserve the `original value` and also the `order` of the values.

We should only add a new date `value` if it is not `Saturday` and if the original `next value` is the next date itself.

The new `df` would look like this:

```
time   
2019-01-04
2019-01-06       
2019-01-01
2019-01-02   
2019-01-07
2019-01-08 
2019-01-03
2019-01-04
....
```

Note that we did not put `2017-01-05` after `2017-01-04` because `2017-01-05` is `Saturday` so we put `2017-01-06`. Also, note that the value after `2019-01-03` is `2019-01-04` because `2019-01-03` is the original date and `2019-01-04` is the next `date`.

We preserve the order and do not remove duplicate.

**What did I do?**

I figured out how to skip `Saturday` by doing this:

```
df[df.index.dayofweek != 5]
```

But I do not know how to find the `next day` and skip if it `Saturday`. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

#### Update per question modification and comment below.

```
new_days = pd.Series(np.where(df['time'].dt.dayofweek != 4, 
                              df['time'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1), 
                              df['time'] + pd.Timedelta(days=2)), 
                     name='time')

pd.concat([df['time'], new_days]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
0   2019-01-04
0   2019-01-06
1   2019-01-01
1   2019-01-02
2   2019-01-07
2   2019-01-08
3   2019-01-03
3   2019-01-04
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

You can try something like this using loc with lambda function and the dt accessor:

```
pd.concat([df['time'], 
           (df['time'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).loc[lambda x: x.dt.dayofweek!=5]])\
  .sort_index()
```

Output:

```
0   2019-01-04
1   2019-01-01
1   2019-01-02
2   2019-01-07
2   2019-01-08
3   2019-01-03
3   2019-01-04
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: We are not supposed to sort the values and preserve the original. The only changes that are expected is to have a new date below the current date value if it is not Saturday and if it is not actually the next day itself

**Updated the question for better clarity**

Comment: This is very close. The only thing that is missing is the `Date` after `Saturday`. Looks like it is not putting any date if the next day is `Saturday`. If the next date is `Saturday` then we add the `Sunday` `Date`

Comment: @floss See update in the top solution 1-04 and 1-6 is next.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `top solution 1-04 and 1-6 is next`

Comment: Just under the bold "Update per..." using np.where.  There is a date 01-04 and the next date is 01-06... skipping the Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out but you can do something like this:

```
for index, date in df.iterrows():
    temp_day = row['Date'] if (row['Date'] + timedelta(days=1)).weekday() != 5 else None
    if(temp_day):
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': temp_day}, index=index+1)
        df = pd.concat(df.iloc[:index], temp_df, df.iloc[index+1:], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

You basically iterate through each index, get the date and add 1 day, and keep it if it doesn't equal a saturday.

Then with slicing, you concat the new row right after the current index